# HTML/Javascript/jquery function Button to place comma at end of each line in TextArea

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, button

I currently have a little HTML window I use at work to automatically Capitalize All, Alphabetize, and Capitalize first letters of contents entered into a `<TextArea>` on the HTML. I was hoping to find a method to add an additional "Comma" Button (`<input type="submit">`) - so it will automatically add a comma to the end of each line in the `<TextArea>`.

Comment: Will these be where the line is forced to wrap to the next or will it be a new line created by you?

Comment: The lines will already be laid out and not wrap, they'll all be set as individual lines before Auto-Comma is added

Comment: Hint, use string replace or regular expression when creating the function for this problem. You just need to replace the characters "\r\n" with ";\r\n" and you're good to go. You may use plain vanilla JS for this.

Comment: Hmm. Well I really have no idea how I can go about doing this, so any examples would be great.

Comment: I've given you the steps below, it's up for you to do the rest. Is this your homework?

Comment: No it's for work to make things easier.

Answer (score 1):

**Steps**

1. Put the content of the textarea in a variable, say 'textareaContent'
2. Find all occurrences of "\r\n" and replace with ";\r\n"

EDIT.

HTML + JS

```
<script>
function addComma()
{
    // get textarea's content
    var content = document.getElementById('myTextArea').value;  

    // replace all newline's with ';\n'
    var replaced = content.replace(/\n/g,';\n');  

    // rewrite the content with the new content
    document.getElementById('myTextArea').value = replaced; }
</script>
<textarea id='myTextArea' rows='5' cols='30'>
First Line
Second Line
Third Line
</textarea>

<input type='button' onclick='addComma()' value='Add Comma' />
```

Anyways, this is an example, in live action. See the fiddle here -- http://jsfiddle.net/u6b7yz21/
Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you are trying to accomplish.

```js
function comma(){
    var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea').value;
    var res = textarea.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,",\r\n");
    console.log(res);
    document.getElementById('textarea').value = res;
}
```

```css
textarea {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
<button onclick="comma()">Comma</button>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much. This removes the tedium of adding a comma at the end of everything I have to do here at work!